# Append Blob into a FormData from img src

Tags: javascript, blob

My question is, how can I create a blob from an image src? I selected an image, this image is resized and displayed in a preview like this:

```
<img id="preview" src="blob:9047F39E-42D2-47BB-86BF-497AF106A941">
```

Now I want to upload the resized image.

```
var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append("file", myBlob, "resize.png");
```

How can I create myBlob using the src of the preview and then append to upload? I tried different ways but has not worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've got a `blob:` URI scheme, it means that somewhere you've called `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`. So you already have this blob. Just keep it somewhere you'll be able to access from your uploading code.

Comment: @Kaiido You were right!, I only declared `var myBlob = new Blob();` at the beginning and I added the line `myBlob = blob;` after I added the src in `document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` and that's all. Append the new image with `formData.append("file", myBlob, "resize.png");`. Thank you!

Comment: You could just declare `var myBlob;` blank instead of creating an empty and useless blob object.